# How to avoid java.security.cert.CertificateException with AuthorizeNet connection?

Tags: java, security, connection, authorize.net

I need to connect with AuthorizeNet but I am getting:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching certification.authorize.net found (Please, see the error trace below).

The URL I use is https://certification.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll

The connection code in my class AuthorizeNet is as follows:

```
        URL url = new URL(“https://certification.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll”);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
```

The error trace is as follows:

2015-04-06 13:00:52,592 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] ERROR com.aaa.AuthorizeNet:541 - 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching certification.authorize.net found.
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.aaa.AuthorizeNet.startNetConnection(AuthorizeNet.java:533)

Comment: If you are testing in the sandbox, the correct endpoint is https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll

Also check the blog post regarding upgrades to sandbox security and infrastructure - http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Authorize-Net-Begins-Infrastructure-and-SHA-2-Certificate/ba-p/49615

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the old URL for connection, this gave the error. The new real URL is https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll.  Then one needs to get LoginID and transaction Key from AuthorizeNet.  If you are a merchant you can get LoginID/TransactionKey that allow you testing transactions

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by running client with these extra params: `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` Ref: [Paypal SSLHandshakeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692724/paypal-sslhandshakeexception)

In another case the below snippet helped me in solving the issue:

```
urlCon.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session){
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: In case of second solution, try using HttpsURLConnection instead of URLConnection.